# How does this strange I/O method work?

Tags: c++, io

While taking input output in C++ I have only used scanf/printf and cin/cout. Now I recently came across [this](http://codeforces.com/contest/86/submission/22526466) code taking I/O in a strange fashion.

Also note that this I/O method is causing the code to run extremely fast, as this code uses almost the same algorithm as most of the other codes but it executes in a much smaller time. Why is this I/O so fast and how does this work in general?

edit: code

```
 #include <bits/stdtr1c++.h>

 #define MAXN 200010
 #define MAXQ 200010
 #define MAXV 1000010
 #define clr(ar) memset(ar, 0, sizeof(ar))
 #define read() freopen("lol.txt", "r", stdin)

 using namespace std;

 const int block_size = 633;

 long long res, out[MAXQ]; int n, q, ar[MAXN], val[MAXN], freq[MAXV];

 namespace fastio{
     int ptr, ye;
     char temp[25], str[8333667], out[8333669];

     void init(){
         ptr = 0, ye = 0;
         fread(str, 1, 8333667, stdin);
     }

     inline int number(){
         int i, j, val = 0;

         while (str[ptr] < 45 || str[ptr] > 57) ptr++;
         while (str[ptr] > 47 && str[ptr] < 58) val = (val * 10) + (str[ptr++] - 48);
         return val;
     }

     inline void convert(long long x){
         int i, d = 0;

         for (; ;){
             temp[++d] = (x % 10) + 48;
             x /= 10;
             if (!x) break;
         }
         for (i = d; i; i--) out[ye++] = temp[i];
         out[ye++] = 10;
     }

     inline void print(){
         fwrite(out, 1, ye, stdout);
     } }

 struct query{
     int l, r, d, i;

     inline query() {}
     inline query(int a, int b, int c){
         i = c;
         l = a, r = b, d = l / block_size;
     }

     inline bool operator < (const query& other) const{
         if (d != other.d) return (d < other.d);
         return ((d & 1) ? (r < other.r) : (r > other.r));
     } } Q[MAXQ];

 void compress(int n, int* in, int* out){
     unordered_map <int, int> mp;
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) out[i] = mp.emplace(in[i], mp.size()).first->second; }

 inline void insert(int i){
     res += (long long)val[i] * (1 + 2 * freq[ar[i]]++); }

 inline void erase(int i){
     res -= (long long)val[i] * (1 + 2 * --freq[ar[i]]); }

 inline void run(){
     sort(Q, Q + q);
     int i, l, r, a = 0, b = 0;

     for (res = 0, i = 0; i < q; i++){
         l = Q[i].l, r = Q[i].r;
         while (a > l) insert(--a);
         while (b <= r) insert(b++);
         while (a < l) erase(a++);
         while (b > (r + 1)) erase(--b);
         out[Q[i].i] = res;
     }
     for (i = 0; i < q; i++) fastio::convert(out[i]); }

 int main(){
     fastio::init();
     int n, i, j, k, a, b;

     n = fastio::number();
     q = fastio::number();
     for (i = 0; i < n; i++) val[i] = fastio::number();
     compress(n, val, ar);

     for (i = 0; i < q; i++){
         a = fastio::number();
         b = fastio::number();
         Q[i] = query(a - 1, b - 1, i);
     }

     run();
     fastio::print();
     return 0; }
```

Comment: please make the question self-sustained. That is, it shouldn't be dependent on content outside of this site. Post the relevant code in the question.

Comment: Are you asking why this `char str[8333667]; fread(str, 1, 8333667, stdin);` could be faster then other methods? Please add the relevant part of that code to your question.

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: @bolov added the code.

Comment: @Bob__ I want to know how does this I/O work

Comment: This code uses task-specific parsing, which is faster than scanf or c++ iostream cin, because this code only parse small subset of many possible number formats and do not check input for errors. There is just less logic in this code, less branches, so it is faster. And there is only 1 syscall to read full file at once with fread into memory, not many syscalls and small 4KB or like buffer with classic scanf/cin.

Comment: In `init`, [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fread) reads once a big chunk of data from stdin into the buffer `str`, then `number` extracts integers from that (updating the current position). As osgx said, less syscalls and almost no error checking make this code "fast".

Comment: @Bob__@osgx what does error checking mean? Error in what sense?

Comment: @akka To check for errors? Like what happens if the file can not be opened? Or there is an error reading from the file? Or if there's an error parsing the contents? Those (and more) conditions needs to be checked for and handled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution, http://codeforces.com/contest/86/submission/22526466 (624 ms, 32 MB RAM uses) uses single fread and manual parsing of numbers from memory (so it uses more memory); many other solutions are slower and uses `scanf` (http://codeforces.com/contest/86/submission/27561563 1620 ms 9MB) or C++ iostream `cin` (http://codeforces.com/contest/86/submission/27558562 3118 ms, 15 MB). Not all difference of solutions comes from input-output and parsing (solutions methods have differences too), but some is.

```
 fread(str, 1, 8333667, stdin);
```

This code uses single `fread` libcall to read up to 8MB, which is full file. The file may have up to 2 (n,t) + 200000 (a_i) + 2*200000 (l,r) 6/7-digit numbers with or without line breaks or separated by one (?) space, so around 8 chars max for number (6 or 7 for number, as 1000000 is allowed too, and 1 space or `\n`); max input file size is like 0.6 M * 8 bytes =~ 5 MB.

```
 inline int number(){
     int i, j, val = 0;

     while (str[ptr] < 45 || str[ptr] > 57) ptr++;
     while (str[ptr] > 47 && str[ptr] < 58) val = (val * 10) + (str[ptr++] - 48);
     return val;
 }
```

Then code uses manual code of parsing decimal int numbers. According to ascii table, http://www.asciitable.com/ decimal codes of 48...57 are decimal digits (second while loop): `'0'...'9'`, and we can just subtract 48 from the letter code to get the digit; multiply partially read `val` by 10 and add current digit. And `chr<45 || chr > 57` in the first while loops sound like skipping non-digits from input. This is incorrect, as this code will not parse codes 45, 46, 47 = `'-', '.', '/'`, and no any number after these chars will be read.

```
 n = fastio::number();
 q = fastio::number();
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++) val[i] = fastio::number();

 for (i = 0; i < q; i++){
     a = fastio::number();
     b = fastio::number();
```

Actual reading uses this `fastio::number()` method; and other solutions uses calling of `scanf` or iostream `operator <<` in loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &(arr[i]));
    add(arr[i]);
}
```

or

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    cin >> a[i];
```

Both methods are more universal, but they do library call, which will read some chars from internal buffer (like 4KB) or call OS syscall for buffer refill, and every function does many checks and has error reporting: For every number of input scanf will reparse the same [format string of first argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string), and will do all the logic described in POSIX http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fscanf.html and all error-checking. C++ iostream has no format string, but it is still more universal: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/istream.tcc#L156 '`operator>>(int& __n)`'.

So, standard library functions have more logic inside, more calls, more branching; and they are more universal and much safer, and should be used in real-world programming. And this "sport programming" contest allow users to solve the task with standard library functions which are fast enough, if you can imagine the algorithm. Authors or task are required to write several solutions with standard i/o functions to check that timelimit of the task is correct and task can be solved. (The TopCoder system is better with i/o, you will not implement i/o, the data is already passed into your function in some language structs/collections).

Sometimes tasks in [sport programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_programming) have tight limits on memory: input files several times bigger than allowed memory usage, and programmer can't read whole file into memory. For example: get 20 mln of digits of single verylong number from input file and add 1 to it, with memory limit of 2 MB; you can't read full input number from file in forward direction; it is very hard to do correct reading in chunks in backward direction; and you just need to forget standard method of addition  (Columnar addition) and build FSM (Finite-state machine) with state, counting sequences of `9`s.

Comment: I wonder if the performance would be improved by either disabling buffering on `stdin` via `setbuf( stdin, NULL );` or simply calling `read( STDIN_FILENO, str, 8333667 );` instead of `fread(...);`.  That might shave a few milliseconds, perhaps.

Comment: disabling buffering with scanf/cin will make thing slower (more syscalls), and this "fastio" just should never be used; in any form, both read and fread, with or without setbuf. It is just incorrect and unsafe and unneeded/unrequired Premature Optimization, http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization. ""We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%""

Comment: *disabling buffering with scanf/cin will make thing slower (more syscalls)* That would depend on the underlying implementation - it could very well result in *less* syscalls.  *this "fastio" just should never be used* True in general, but for code IO performance competitions the winner is almost guaranteed to have to do something like it.

Comment: Andrew, the competition is not for doing microoptimization of I/O, it is about computing the answer; any I/O style will be accepted in this task and will pass the timelimit. No, disabling buffering will not help 800000 scanf to be faster; with libc input buffering there will be ~1600 sycalls, without - 800000 syscalls or even  several millions of them (scanf [does byte reads](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/ee19f1de0d0da24114be554fdf94243c0ec6b86c/stdio-common/vfscanf.c#L1403) with `inchar()` = `_IO_getc_unlocked (s)`), and syscall is always slower than libcall.

Comment: The posted code does no internal timing, so the IO time is measured along with the processing time.  *No, disabling buffering will not help 800000 scanf to be faster;* You've benchmarked it?  On different implementations?  You do know that in general the absolute fastest way to read data from a file into a process's address space is to disable all buffering along the way by using direct IO and reading into page-aligned buffers?  That's not usually used though because if you want to read the data again you have to go all the way back to the disk. But if you *know* you're only reading it once...

Comment: Andrew, The implementation is known, the glibc (default for linux, and used in [cygwin/WSoL](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/79)). It is user-space buffering of data, read from kernel. You may benchmark 3 ways of reading data (fread(8MB)+posted pasring, scanf, cin), and scanf+zero vbuf and post results as separate answer. I still think that less syscalls is faster. You can also assume that source data is read not from I/O device but from memory (page cache).